# installshield service pack system requirement

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield, installshield-le

my question is pretty simple so here it is:

Using InstallShield, whatever version, is there anyway to specify a Service Pack as a System Hardware Requirements?

I can specify Windows 7, so that my installation will not even be launched if the OS is prior to Win7 but I also want to specify a minimal service pack, which seems to be simply impossible to do.

Another... hum inconsistency, is that I can set a certain OS AND service pack requirements for  a specific prerequisite but all it does is remove the prerequisite from the installation if its requirements are not met but it won't cancel the installation itself, even if the prerequisite is mandatory... *sigh* /rant :P

Anyways, if anyone has an idea how to do that with InstallShield, that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pls go through this below mentioned link.... for different Install condition

http://blogs.flexerasoftware.com/installtalk/2010/11/using-msi-launch-conditions-to-prevent-installation-on-unsupported-windows-platforms.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! Editing the conditions manualy is a bit of a pain but the interface pop an error when I select Win7, Win8 and Win8.1. So manual editing it is! I only have one more issue now. prerequisites are installed BEFORE the install conditions are checked...

Comment: Seems like the only way to avoid installing the prerequisites before the install conditions are checked is to edit every prerequisite and make sure their conditions are the same as the install conditions, its annoying but at least it works.